# MVC3 retrieving partial view value by an element ID. What's the solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Sorry to bother, I'm fairly new to MVC3 and I've been looking for 3 days but no solution.

The problem looks like this. I have a view which has another partial view in it using `@html.Partial`.

In the partial view I have a double select box which allows me to move users from one side to another.

My question is when I post my main form how can I also post the information from my partial form also, more precisely the second select box data, because I've tried everything yet no success. Also here is the code, and your help is highly appreciated.

The Main View: (not copied from the beginning as I don't think it helps)

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.Voyage.DateOfArrival, new { @class = "date", id = "arrival" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(v => v.Voyage.MarginOfErrorTime, "Allowed margin of error")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(v => v.Voyage.MarginOfErrorTime)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="partial-view">
        @Html.Partial("_UserAddingOptions", Model)
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

This is the partial view:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.configureBoxes();
});
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Filter:<br />
            <input type="text" id="box1Filter" style="width: 160px;" />
            <button type="button" id="box1Clear">
                X</button><br />
            <select id="box1View" multiple="multiple" style="height: 240px; width: 200px;">
                @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
                {
                    <option>@user.FirstName @user.LastName</option>
                }
            </select><br />
            <span id="box1Counter" class="countLabel"></span>
            <select id="box1Storage">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 28px; vertical-align: middle;">
            <button id="to2" type="button">
                ></button>
            <button id="to1" type="button">
                <</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            Filter:<br />
            <input type="text" id="box2Filter" style="width: 160px;" />
            <button type="button" id="box2Clear">
                X</button><br />
            <select id="box2View" multiple="multiple" style="height: 240px; width: 200px;">
            </select><br />
            <span id="box2Counter" class="countLabel"></span>
            <select id="box2Storage">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

I only have a controller for the main view, what viable solutions do I have to post the partial view info from (id = box2View) to the controller when I submit the main form?

Comment: where do you have the submit button and the form? in the main view or the partial view?:

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My submit button is in the main form. When i click the submit button everything gets posted back from the main form to my controller just fine, but nothing from the partial and thats what drives me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two mistakes I can see, and one advisory:

1) You have a nested form there - unless there are other views on which the partial is used to submit stuff in its own right (probably not, since you are using `BeginForm` it's always posting back to the current Controller/View).  Get rid of the form tag on the partial view.

2) ...And this is the main issue - none of your inputs on the partial have `name`s.  If they don't have `name`s then they don't submit anything:

```
<select id="box2View" name="box2View" ...
```

3) You're a self-confessed beginner, I know - so you'll benefit from me advising you to look over some walkthrough guides on model-binding.  Manually writing out all your form elements, manually spitting out `option` tags etc, is unnecessary.  The simple MSDN topic [Models and Validation in Asp.Net MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx) is worth taking a look at - in particular note the view code there - everything is done from the model, no explicit `<input type="textbox"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have the submot button outside the form, either you move it into the form that is inside the partial view within the code block `@Html.BeginForm()` or use javascript to post the form when it is clicked on.

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#someForm').submit();" /> //someForm is id of the form.
```

Comment: ok, but then how can i see the info from the second selectbox, for example if i put a breakpoint at my controller i can only see the main form data retrieved only (the model) and no other object. Must i use a the viewDataDictionary to see the values? or what other solution is there?

Comment: either you need to wrap your entire content that you want posted in the form block or create a n ajax request in javascript and the data that you want to send over can be selectd from the DOM. Read about jquery ajax

Comment: sorry if im annoying you (im a rookie) but more specifically wrap it up in what? i have no html helper for the <select> tag and i dont want to use ajax as i want all my info sent in one post. An example would by highly valuable.

Comment: your Html.BeginForm() should contain all the controls that you want posted back to the server and please google you will find adequate examples..

Comment: you cant get customized solution for every problem here.. you need to do things on your own..